ORtools VRP: at a given location, limit number of vehicles at each time
I have a vehicle routing problem that I'm trying to solve with ortools for python.
My depot is at location 0. For each assignment i->j (which means pickup at location i, delivery at location j) I create distinct nodes i and j. Depot creates another distinct node. Since assignments can have common endpoints, this means that each location is duplicated into several nodes. In a dataframe, I store each nodes original location.
For assignments, each load and unload time lasts for 10min. I have a dimension VehicleTotalTime (with slack and needs not start at 0) that measures how many seconds each vehicle spent. How do I create constraints that at depot, there are at most 5 vehicles at any given time, and at stores, there is at most 1 vehicle at any given time?
Is there a way to create a dimension for each location, that counts how many vehicles are there at each time?

TLDR: Please take a look at the resource constraints guide:
https://developers.google.com/optimization/routing/cvrptw_resources

I still have a problem with duplications. If I have assignments i->j and i->k, the location i is duplicated into nodes i1 and i2. With solver.FixedDurationIntervalVar(time_dimension.CumulVar(index), ...)) I specify the interval at index/node, not at location. If I set this interval to be the same for i1 and i2, then use solver.Add(solver.Cumulative(intervals, usage, docking_capacity, f"capacity_{node}"), a feasible solution will be that there are docking_capacity vehicles at i1 and at i2 at the same time, but that would mean 2*docking_capacity at location i, which is not feasible.

Now, I could assign 1/2 and 1/2 of docking_capacity to i1 and i2, or 1/4 and 3/4, or 1/3 and 2/3, ..., but covering all the combinations (actually integer compositions of docking_capacity) would complicate the situation, and I don't know how to use or between those combinations.

Do I create for each node a list intervals, then for nodes belonging to the same location, I join those lists into a single one and call solver.Cumulative(intervals, ...) on it?
